# junit tearDownClass() vs tearDown()

Tags: junit

What is difference between tearDownClass() & tearDown() methods?

Where can I find documentation for both.

junit.org documentation of JUnit listed only tearDown() not tearDownClass(): 
         http://www.junit.org/apidocs/junit/framework/TestCase.html#setUp()

Comment: If the JUnit docs don't refer to it, where did you get it from?

Comment: What version of JUnit are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [difference-between-setup-and-setupbeforeclass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413092/difference-between-setup-and-setupbeforeclass)

Answer (score 6):

Use the API's tearDownAfterClass() and tearDown() with the Annotations @AfterClass and @After.
The code within tearDownAfterClass() would be executed only once after all the unit tests written in Junit have been executed. Clean up code can be written here to release the resources after all the tests have been executed.
The code within tearDown() would be executed after executing each of the test scenarios.

These API's are part of JUnit 4.

Below is a sample code to understand the invocation of these API's:

public class TestJUnit {

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Executing a JUNIT test file");
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Execution of JUNIT test file done");
}

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Executing a new test");
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Execution done");
}

@Test
public void test1() {
    System.out.println("test1 ...");
}

@Test 
public void test2(){
    System.out.println("test2 ...");        
}
```

}

**Output:** 
Executing a JUNIT test file
Executing a new test
test1
Execution done
Executing a new test
test2
Execution done
Execution of JUNIT test file done

The API's setUpBeforeClass() and setUp() with the Annotations @BeforeClass and @Before respectively would behave as follows:

setUpBeforeClass - Useful to have initialization code here. Code written in this method would get executed only once and execution would happen prior to execution of the individual tests.

setUp() - Code within this block would get executed prior to each of the individual tests.

Answer (score 3):

There's a [AfterClass](http://www.junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/AfterClass.html) annotation in the JUnit 4.x API, is that what you meant?

`tearDown` occurs after executing each test method of the TestCase. There is a separate hook (the AfterClass I linked to) that executes after all the test methods of the TestCase have run.

I don't think the 3.x Junit API had any concept of an after-class teardown. Maybe you're thinking of TestNG?

Comment: JUnit 3 **did not** have `tearDownClass()`, this is however what I call my methods annotated with `@AfterClass`.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen the Java unittesting seems to match Python pretty closely, so if JUnit is the same as the Python testcases I'm working with then in a testcase class `setUp()` and `tearDown()` are called before and after every `test()` you write.

`setUpClass()` and `tearDownClass()` are called once at the beginning and end of a particular testcase class.

So to illustrate this in what I'm doing I have in Python:

```
class exampleUnitTest(SeleniumTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # setup each test

    def test1(self):
        # run test process

    def test2(self):
        # run test process

    def tearDown(self):
        # teardown each test

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        # teardown at end of all tests
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand *@After* & *@AfterClass* I want to provide this code sample:

```
public class ExampleTest {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExampleTest.class);

    /**
     * This method won't be executed if the unit test will be (externally) terminated (e.g. from within the IDE).
     * You have to act **really** fast in this case.
     */
    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() throws Exception {
        LOG.info("@BeforeClass"); // will be always executed, even if a test fails throwing any Exception
    }

    /**
     * This method won't be executed if the unit test will be (externally) terminated (e.g. from within the IDE).
     */
    @AfterClass
    public static void afterClass() throws Exception {
        // executed after the class has been initialized, only once
        LOG.info("@AfterClass"); // will be always executed, even if a test fails throwing any Exception
    }

    /**
     * This method won't be executed if the unit test will be (externally) terminated (e.g. from within the IDE).
     * You have to act *really* fast in this case.
     */
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        LOG.info("@Before"); // will be always executed, even if a test fails throwing any Exception
    }

    /**
     * This method won't be executed if the unit test will be (externally) terminated (e.g. from within the IDE).
     */
    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        // executed for every single unit test (annotated with @Test) within this test class
        LOG.info("@After"); // will be always executed, even if a test fails throwing any Exception
    }

    @Test
    public void someTest() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(10000); // interrupts current "main" Thread in the "main" thread group
        throw new Error("VM Error"); // allowed as Exception is part of this test method's signature ("throws" clause)
    }
}
```